# How to replace certain string without certain occurrence

Tags: c#, string, replace, pattern-matching

**For example text here:**

`text = "Chapter 44. 7h3 v3nd3774"`

I want it output like this

`outcome = "Chapter 44. The colosseum"`

If I simply use method like this:

`string s = text.Replace("4", "a").Replace("3", "e").Replace("6", "g").Replace("1", "I").Replace("0", "o").Replace("5", "s").Replace("7", "t");`

`System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", s);`

will output as `Chapter aa. the vendetta`, correct part also change, wondering if there would be some simple solutions?

Comment: What is logic of this replacement?

Comment: How do you know which part is the correct part?

Comment: If you can express the logic rules used to determine which numbers should be converted, then yes, that should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can express the logic rules used to determine which numbers should be converted, then yes, that should not be too difficult.

From your example it appears that you only want to change the number to a letter if it's directly adjacent to a letter. If that's the only rule, then you can do something like this:

```
public static string Translate(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;

    var charMap = new Dictionary<char, char>
    {
        {'4', 'a'}, {'3', 'e'}, {'6', 'g'}, {'1', 'i'},
        {'0', 'o'}, {'5', 's'}, {'7', 't'}
    };

    var suffixes = new List<string>
    {
        "st", "nd", "rd", "th"
    };

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // If the previous or next character is a letter and this character
        // is in the mapping dictionary, replace it with the mapped character
        if (((i > 0 && char.IsLetter(result[i - 1])) ||
                (i < input.Length - 1 && char.IsLetter(input[i + 1]))) &&
            charMap.ContainsKey(input[i]) && 
            (i == input.Length - 1 || !IsValidSuffix(input.Substring(i + 1), suffixes)))
        {
            result.Append(charMap[input[i]]);

            // Because we're changing characters from left to right and we just
            // changed this character to a letter, we need to walk backwards and 
            // check the previous characters since they may now need to change.
            // For example the 51 in '517u4710n' would not change without this check
            var prevIndex = i - 1;
            while (prevIndex >= 0 && charMap.ContainsKey(result[prevIndex]))
            {
                result[prevIndex] = charMap[result[prevIndex]];
                prevIndex--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

// Helper method to determine if a number is followed by a "valid suffix", 
// which is used to prevent converting numbers when they should remain
// numbers; such as "24th", where we don't want to change the '4' to an 'a'.
public static bool IsValidSuffix(string input, List<string> validSuffixes)
{
    if (input == null) return validSuffixes == null;
    if (input == string.Empty) return true;
    if ((validSuffixes?.Count).GetValueOrDefault() == 0) return false;

    var match = validSuffixes
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
        .FirstOrDefault(input.StartsWith);

    return match != null &&
            (input.Length == match.Length ||
            !char.IsLetter(input[match.Length]));
}

// Output: Translate("Chapter 44. 7h3 v3nd3774") == "Chapter 44. the vendetta"
```

Comment: Yes this solution indeed output the most accurate output except one exception "On the 24th of February, 1815, " output as "On the 2ath of February, 1815, " (while the original one not need translate)

Comment: As I mentioned, we need the logic rules used to determine which numbers should be replaced. If you specify the rules I will update the code.

Comment: I added some code to fulfill that rule, but I'll let you add your own rules if you figure out some more! ::)

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is to keep whole numbers as 'correct' parts, you could try to find these numbers after applying your Replace logic and put them back in your 'corrected' sentence.
Also when you change a string many times I advise using StringBuilder for performance issues.

Here is a code suggestion:
`

```
void Main()
{
    var text = "Chapter 44. 7h3 v3nd3774";
    var outcome = RemoveLeet(text);
    Console.WriteLine(outcome);
}

bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

bool IsLetter(char c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z';
}

string RemoveLeet(string text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    sb
    .Replace("4", "a").Replace("3", "e").Replace("6", "g").Replace("1", "I")
    .Replace("0", "o").Replace("5", "s").Replace("7", "t");
    var outcome = sb.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length;)
    {
        if (IsDigit(text[i++]))
        {
            int numberLength = 1;
            for (;i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!IsDigit(text[i]))
                    break;
                numberLength += 1;
            }
            var indexBeforeNumber = i - numberLength - 1;
            //check number did not start inside a word
            if (indexBeforeNumber < 0 || !IsLetter(text[indexBeforeNumber]))
            {
                //check number is not followed by a word
                if (i == text.Length || !IsLetter(text[i]))
                {
                    var number = text.Substring(i - numberLength, numberLength);
                    var outcomeBegin = indexBeforeNumber < 1 ? "" : outcome.Substring(0, indexBeforeNumber + 1);
                    var outcomeAfter = i == text.Length ? "" : outcome.Substring(i, text.Length - i);
                    outcome = $"{outcomeBegin}{number}{outcomeAfter}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

`

Comment: FYI, the `char` type already has static `IsDigit` and `IsLetter` methods you can use. For example you can do: `if (char.IsDigit(text[i++]))`

Comment: It is leet convert! but no obvious rules provided, i think is text been randomly polluted by leet change and need to decode back, while original texts are normal paragraphs. Not sure if need more information?